# Erro ao tentar consumir WebService: Servidor não reconheceu o valor do cabeçalho

Tags: c#, java, android, web-service

Estou enfrentando o seguinte erro ao tentar ler um WebService:

`SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'O servidor não reconheceu o valor do cabeçalho HTTP SOAPAction: http://temuri.org/HelloWorld.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@17a8faf7`

**Segue meu código em Java Android:**

```
private void webservice(){
        String URN = "http://temuri.org/"; // Namespace do WebService
        String address = "http://192.168.1.105:8090/AngridWeb/WebService.asmx"; // URL do WebService
        String methodName = "HelloWorld";  // Nome do método
        String soapAction = "http://temuri.org/HelloWorld"; // Ação SOAP

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(URN, methodName);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
                new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //request.addProperty("valor", numero);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(address);
        ht.debug = true;
        try {
            ht.call(soapAction, envelope);
            String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            int fatorial = Integer.parseInt(result);
        } catch (org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException ex2) {
            Log.e("Err::", ex2.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = "Err2::" + ex.toString() + '\n' +
                    ht.requestDump + '\n' +
                    ht.responseDump + '\n';
            Log.e("Erro:", msg);
        }
    }
```

Ja tentei de várias maneiras. Mudando o `soapAction` também.

`String soapAction = "http://temuri.org/AngridWeb/HelloWorld";`

**Meu WebService, bem simples, feito em `C#`:**

```
namespace AngridWebServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Ele está hospedado em meu IIS.

Estou usando a biblioteca KSoap2 para consumir o WebService.

Comment: Seu web service tá com `Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/"` e no android você está passando para a `URN = "http://temuri.org/"`, assim como no soap_action. Dá uma conferida se é isso, ai coloco de resposta.

Comment: Pior que era isso mesmo, @MuriloFechio kkkkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Namespace do Web Service e os campos do cabeçalho SOAP devem ser os mesmos. No caso: `Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/"`, portanto a URN deve ter o mesmo valor do Namespace, assim como sua requisição do soapAction.

Comment: Correto! Me distraí na hora de colocar os valores.