# Erro de permissão a fazer uma chamada SOAP com aXMLRPC

Tags: android, magento, soap

Fala galera!

Tenho uma loja virtual (Magento) na qual estou tentando fazer uma requisição SOAP com ksoap2 no Android. Porém, ao executar o código, ele gera uma exception, mas, a mensagem dessa exception retorna `@null`. Segue abaixo o código que utilizei:

```
package com.devx3.mageorderconsult.WS;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpRetryException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;

import de.timroes.axmlrpc.XMLRPCClient;
import de.timroes.axmlrpc.XMLRPCException;

/**
 * Created by erick on 10/18/15.
 */
public class WSMagento {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
    public String url;
    public String user;
    public String token;

    public WSMagento( String url, String user, String token ) {
        this.url  = url;
        this.user  = user;
        this.token = token;
    }

    public void callMagentoStore() {

        try {
            SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            env.dotNet = false;
            env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");

            request.addProperty("username", user);
            request.addProperty("apiKey", token);

            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

            androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
            Object result = env.getResponse();

            Log.d("DEVX3", result.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DEVX3", "Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIÇÃO 20/10/2015**

Bem galera, desisti de utilizar o Ksoap por várias críticas que vi sobre a lib. Passei a utilizar o XMLRPCCLient Android. Mas, ainda estou tendo problemas, porém agora é com permissão de conexão com a internet.

Segue abaixo meus arquivos:

WSMagento.java:

```
package com.devx3.mageorderconsult.WS;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException;

import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Created by erick on 10/18/15.
 */
public class WSMagento {

    public static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
    public AsyncTask<String, String, String> sessionId;
    public String url;
    public String user;
    public String apiKey;

    public WSMagento( String url, String user, String apiKey ) {
        this.url  = url;
        this.user  = user;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public void callMagentoStore(){

        sessionId = new ClientXMLRPCTask().execute(url, user, apiKey);

        Log.d("DEVX3", "SessionID: "+sessionId);
    }



    public String toString() {
        return "URL: "+url+" - USER: "+user+" - APIKEY: "+apiKey;
    }
}
```

ClientXMLRPCTask.java:

```
package com.devx3.mageorderconsult.WS;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient;
import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException;

import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Created by erick on 10/20/15.
 */
public class ClientXMLRPCTask extends AsyncTask <String, String, String> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params){
        URI    url    = URI.create(params[0]);
        String user   = params[1];
        String apiKey = params[2];

        XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(url);
        String session = null;
        try {
            session = (String) client.call("login", user, apiKey);
        } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
            Log.e("DEVX3", "Error ClientXMLRPCTask", e);
        } finally {
            return session;
        }

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.devx3.mageorderconsult" >

    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".OrdersListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Exception gerada:

```
SessionID: com.devx3.mageorderconsult.WS.ClientXMLRPCTask@424c1b88
 Error ClientXMLRPCTask
 org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
    at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:237)
    at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.call(XMLRPCClient.java:297)
    at com.devx3.mageorderconsult.WS.ClientXMLRPCTask.doInBackground(ClientXMLRPCTask.java:24)
    at com.devx3.mageorderconsult.WS.ClientXMLRPCTask.doInBackground(ClientXMLRPCTask.java:14)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:178)
    ... 10 more
 Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
    ... 20 more
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    ... 23 more
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada se isso te ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56062/erro-ao-tentar-consumir-webservice-servidor-n%C3%A3o-reconheceu-o-valor-do-cabe%C3%A7alho/56069#

Comment: Então cara, desisti do ksoap... Vi algumas criticas sobre a lib que acabei deixando quieto... Passei a tentar utilizar xmlrpcandroid, mas ainda estou com problemas :(

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque é uma pergunta antiga que está sem resposta e que foi abandonada pelo autor que explicou em um comentário que não tem mais interesse nela.

Comment: Oi Victor, ok, tentei editar para ajudar mas nesse caso vou votar para fechar também